# How name file with timestamp?

Tags: coding-style

This file name must be recognisable like README/INSTALL/AUTHORS/COPING/etc.

So user can easily found them and can determine how old project sources.

I think **ChangeLog** perform such functions but have additional meaning. Or namy be **NEWS**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common name is CHANGES, I think. This will have a dated sections telling the reader what significant updates have been made. ChangeLog is similar, but much more fine-grained (e.g. on the level of individual source repository commits).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I found **CHANGES** in "The Art of Unix Programming" by Eric Steven Raymond, but GNU coding standard don't mention it.